# how to perform post request on nested serailizers in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hii I am new to django rest framework i am able to perform put delete and get operations but unable to perform post operations
models.py

```
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
def __str__(self):
    return "@{}".format(self.username)
class User_log(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth.models.User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_logs')
    fullname=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    fb_login=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

serializers.py

```
class userSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password1=serializers.CharField(source="user.password1",write_only=True)
    password2=serializers.CharField(source="user.password2",write_only=True)
    fullname=serializers.CharField(source='user_logs.fullname')
    fb=serializers.BooleanField(source='user_logs.fb_login')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=('id','username','email','password1','password2','fullname','fb')
        related_fields = ['user_logs']
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # Handle related objects
        for related_obj_name in self.Meta.related_fields:
            data = validated_data.pop(related_obj_name)
            related_instance = getattr(instance, related_obj_name)

            # Same as default update implementation
            for attr_name, value in data.items():
                setattr(related_instance, attr_name, value)
            related_instance.save()
        return super(userSerializers,self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers
router=routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('accounts',views.Userview,basename='user')
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
    path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_email.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('',include(router.urls)),
]
```

views.py

```
class Userview(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
def get_serializer_class(self):
    return userSerializers
def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.all()
def list(self,request):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer=userSerializers(queryset,many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid:
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

this is the json format when i perform get request

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "karm",
    "email": "karm@gmail.com",
    "fullname": "ss",
    "fb": false
}
]
```

As mentioned earliew whenever i perform put delete or get its working but its not a case with post the error i get is this:

```
AssertionError at /accounts/accounts/
```

The `.create()` method does not support writable dotted-source fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `accounts.serializers.userSerializers`, or set `read_only=True` on dotted-source serializer fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points to consider here:

1. DRF Serializers do not support `write_only`. Instead, use `extra_kwargs` in the serializer's `Meta` block.
2. Write a `create` method in your serializer. Rough example below.

See this from the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) for more information about write-only fields in DRF serializers.

```
class userSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password1=serializers.CharField(source="user.password1")
    password2=serializers.CharField(source="user.password2")
    fullname=serializers.CharField(source='user_logs.fullname')
    fb=serializers.BooleanField(source='user_logs.fb_login')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields
        fields=['id','username','email','password1','password2','fullname','fb']
        related_fields = ['user_logs']
        extra_kwargs = {
          'password1': {'write_only': True},
          'password2': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data): // adjust to fit your actual User model
        user = User(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Its Working thanks for that just one more favour i wnat to make password 1 and 2 field writeonly only when request is Post if it is PUT writeonly will be false

Comment: Create a new serializer called UpdateUserSerializer with the permissions you want. In your view, override default patch behavior by writing a new update method within the view that uses UpdateUserSerializer. See DRF docs for more info on overriding default ModelViewSet behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write create method as you are doing with update method. Try this code in your serializer.py file.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
    return user
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: even this is Working thanks for that just one more favour i wnat to make password 1 and 2 field writeonly only when request is Post if it is PUT writeonly will be false